# How to detect first-in first-out special file (named pipe) with dotnet?

Tags: c#, .net, linux, mkfifo

I'd like to identify files that are first-in first-out special file (named pipe) on Linux with dotnet

Here is a kind of file returned by ls:

```
$ ls -al /home/xxxxxx/.mkmkmmkk/sdfsdf.pipe
prw------- 1 xxxxxx xxxxxx 0  4 nov  2018 /home/xxxxxx/.mkmkmmkk/sdfsdf.pipe
```

this kind of file can be created with `mkfifo someFileName`

How can I retrieve the `p` attribute from dotnet without running an external process ?

Thanks

Comment: It would be the first character on each line so you can use substring(0,1) where zero is the index and one the string length.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=net-7.0

Comment: Thanks, @jdweng, but parsing the output of ls would require executing the `ls` program, that I want to avoid

Comment: There is an enumeration for special folders (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder?view=net-7.0).  You need to use : https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2018/11/07/dotnet-special-folder-api-linux#environment_getfolderpath

Comment: Use GetFiles like in following code : https://berserkerdotnet.github.io/blog/detecting-namedpipe-exists/

Comment: @jdweng None of that helps. The question being asked is how to identify that a file is a pipe (as opposed to a directory, a plain file, a socket, etc). In C, you'd use `stat`. Windows provides `GetFileType`, which require file handles rather than paths.

Comment: @manuc66, In unix, it's part of the mode, so I wonder if you can use [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesysteminfo.unixfilemode?view=net-7.0#system-io-filesysteminfo-unixfilemode). Pipes have this bit set: 0x1000

Answer (score 0):

By using interop it's possible to identify if the files are FIFO:

```cs
Sys.LStat("/home/xxxxxx/.mkmkmmkk/sdfsdf.pipe", out Sys.FileStatus fileStatus);
Console.WriteLine((fileStatus.Mode & Sys.FileTypes.S_IFMT) == Sys.FileTypes.S_IFIFO);
```

Here is the supporting interops:

```cs
static class Sys
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct FileStatus
    {
        internal FileStatusFlags Flags;
        internal int Mode;
        internal uint Uid;
        internal uint Gid;
        internal long Size;
        internal long ATime;
        internal long ATimeNsec;
        internal long MTime;
        internal long MTimeNsec;
        internal long CTime;
        internal long CTimeNsec;
        internal long BirthTime;
        internal long BirthTimeNsec;
        internal long Dev;
        internal long Ino;
        internal uint UserFlags;
    }

    internal static class FileTypes
    {
        internal const int S_IFMT = 0xF000;
        internal const int S_IFIFO = 0x1000;
        internal const int S_IFCHR = 0x2000;
        internal const int S_IFDIR = 0x4000;
        internal const int S_IFREG = 0x8000;
        internal const int S_IFLNK = 0xA000;
        internal const int S_IFSOCK = 0xC000;
    }

    [Flags]
    internal enum FileStatusFlags
    {
        None = 0,
        HasBirthTime = 1,
    }

    [DllImport("libSystem.Native", EntryPoint = "SystemNative_FStat", SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern int FStat(SafeHandle fd, out FileStatus output);

    [DllImport("libSystem.Native", EntryPoint = "SystemNative_Stat", SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern int Stat(string path, out FileStatus output);

    [DllImport("libSystem.Native", EntryPoint = "SystemNative_LStat", SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern int LStat(string path, out FileStatus output);
}
```